# List last logged users (GROUP BY and ORDER BY)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables (`user` and `log`), and I would like to show all users by ordering by the lasts results. I'm using the `GROUP BY` for join the logs (because Each user has more than one log), until then it works well, but when I added the ORDER BY, showed me a error.

```
SELECT name, log.date 
FROM user 
JOIN log 
ON user.cod = log.cod_user 
GROUP BY user.cod 
ORDER BY log.date
```

> ERROR: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'insidetv.log.date' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: As the error message suggests, add a aggregating function to the column log.date, IOW, ```max(log.date) as `last_date` ```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!